# Javascript Changing Class name error?

Tags: javascript, html

here is my code

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.substr(7, 21) === "www.codtelevision.com")
 {
    //Valid domain
    if (url.substr(29) === "")
    {
        document.getElementById('homeLink').className = "active";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById(url.substr(29) + "Link").className = "active";
    }
}
```

When i look in my chrome developer tools, i see this error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null`

I have tried so many times to fix it but can not. How do i get this to work?

Also, when i just put this in the console, it works:

```
document.getElementById('homeLink').className = "active";
```

My website is [www.codtelevision.com](http://www.codtelevision.com)

Comment: The only reason you will see `Cannot set property [property] of null` is when `getElementById` cannot find an element with the id provided and thus returns null.

Comment: At least one of those elements doesn't exist. Can you set up a jsFiddle example?

Comment: The id is valid though, because when i put this in the console (document.getElementById('homeLink').className = "active";) it works perfectly

Comment: Then it's the `url.substr(29) + "Link"` that is a non-existent ID.

Comment: Well but maybe document.getElementById(url.substr(29) + "Link") is null.

Comment: Can you show your html mark up or prepare a fiddle?

Comment: Look at my website www.codtelevision.com

Comment: Debug the code in developer tools and put a break point on the line in question and check what (url.substr(29) + "Link") returns.

Comment: Before the `if` block, do `console.log(url.substr(29));` to check what's being fed into the `if`, and what *may* be being used within the `if`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish i get undifined

Comment: Then do `if (!url.substr(29))` instead, since you're checking if it's *typechecked* empty string.

Comment: no, i still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your document is not loaded. put your code inside `window.onload` .

```
window.onload = function(){
   //code
}
```

or if you are using **jquery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //code
});
```

Comment: actually, this code takes out the error, but it does not change tha class of the element

Comment: There is nothing such as `document.onload` ([article](http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/2009/05/20/the-day-supporting-document-onload-became-a-bug)), use `window.onload`!